# UPDATE on LEFT JOIN error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, left-join

I have an SQL query which keeps giving me an error.

I have tried multiple ways of writing the query but I have had no luck in fixing it.

I have two tables(table1 and table2) with duplicate columns orgcodeold and orgcode. **table1.orgcode** is empty but **table2.orgcode** is populated.

I am trying to populate **table1.orgcode** with **table2.orgcode** where **table1.orgcodeold=table2.orgcodeold**.

**THE ERROR**

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.
```

**THE QUERY**

```
UPDATE table1 AS t1 
LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2 
ON t2.orgcodeold = t1.orgcodeold 
SET t1.orgcode = t2.orgcode 
WHERE t1.orgcodeold = t2.orgcodeold
```

Please help.

Comment: Does SQL Server support UPDATE JOIN?

Comment: Use Set before Applying join.

Comment: Yes, I have used this before.

Comment: Try the solution suggested by LAMAK.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, you have almost the whole syntax wrong. It should be:

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.orgcode = t2.orgcode 
FROM table1 AS t1 
INNER JOIN table2 AS t2 
    ON t2.orgcodeold = t1.orgcodeold;
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.orgcode = t2.orgcode 
from table1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2 
ON t2.orgcodeold = t1.orgcodeold
```